# android - Same code gives different result in different Activities while pulling JSON data through AsyncTask

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

This is my simple code snippet to pull JSON data from my localhost

```
public class JSONtest extends ActionBarActivity {

private ProgressDialog dialog;

String message3;
String message_short;
String[] items;
String[] short_items;
TextView tv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_jsontest);

    String localhost = "http://10.0.2.2/example/json/notification.php";
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    new ReadJSONFeedTask().execute(localhost);
}

private class ReadJSONFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(JSONtest.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Downloading Notifications. Please wait . . .");
        dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
    }
    protected String doInBackground(String...urls)
    {
        return readJSONFeed(urls[0]);
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        dialog.dismiss();
        try
        {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
            items = new String[jsonArray.length()];
            short_items = new String[jsonArray.length()];
            for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
            {
                JSONObject jobj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                message3 = "PART 1 : " + jobj.getString("subject") + "\n\n" + 
                        "PART 2 : " + jobj.getString("date");
                items[i] = message3;
                message_short = message_short + "\n\n" + message3;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        tv.setText(message_short);
    }
}

public String readJSONFeed(String URL)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet hg = new HttpGet(URL);
    try
    {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(hg);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        if(statusCode == 200)
        {
            HttpEntity en = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = en.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
            String line;
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Log.e("JSON", "Failed to download File");
        }
    }
    catch(ClientProtocolException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
}
```

I used this exact same code in two different Activities in the same app. The only difference was the name of the classes. While one activity works perfect, another activity gives an error as nothing happens and the `TextView` is left black. The log from Logcat for the Activity which does not work is this :

```
11-04 11:14:40.679: W/EGL_emulation(2925): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-04 11:14:40.749: W/System.err(2925): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-04 11:14:40.749: W/System.err(2925):     at com.onclaveinc.ioexception.HomeScreen$ReadJSONFeedTask.onPostExecute(HomeScreen.java:129)
11-04 11:14:40.749: W/System.err(2925):     at com.onclaveinc.ioexception.HomeScreen$ReadJSONFeedTask.onPostExecute(HomeScreen.java:1)
11-04 11:14:40.749: W/System.err(2925):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
11-04 11:14:40.749: W/System.err(2925):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
11-04 11:14:40.749: W/System.err(2925):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
11-04 11:14:40.749: W/System.err(2925):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-04 11:14:40.749: W/System.err(2925):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-04 11:14:40.749: W/System.err(2925):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
11-04 11:14:40.749: W/System.err(2925):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-04 11:14:40.749: W/System.err(2925):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-04 11:14:40.749: W/System.err(2925):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
11-04 11:14:40.749: W/System.err(2925):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
11-04 11:14:40.769: W/System.err(2925):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can anybody please help me with this? I really need both of them to work.

Comment: What is on HomeScreen.java line 129?

Comment: on the HomeScreen activity, after the JSON data is obtained, I want to switch to a next activity. So there's a `startActivity(i);` in line 129. But that is not within the `AsyncTask`. It is after the `new ReadJSONFeedTask().execute(localhost);` line in `onCreate()`. @matiash

Comment: HomeScreen.java line 129 is IN OnPostExecute according to the stack trace. Are you sure it's startActivity ? Something is weird here.

Comment: You should post the code of HomeScreen.java